# How to install ViTables?

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I am trying to install ViTables 3 (an HDF5 file viewer) on MacOS X 10.9.5 with Python 3.6 using the following command:

```
pip3 install ViTables-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

It installs just fine but it still won't start, yielding the following error instead:

```
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I have tried the following to fix this with no luck

```
brew install pyqt5

brew install pyqt
```

Any ideas about how to fix this actually?

I have also installed Anaconda just for this and tried installing ViTables with `conda` (`conda install -c conda-forge vitables`) but it doesn't work this way too, although the error (shown when I try to run ViTables, the installation process seems to complete without errors) is different:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'ViTables==3.0.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

PS: I've also tried HDFView but it says there's not enough memory to open the file I need (I am almost sure ViTables will manage - it opens the same file just fine on a much older Linux machine).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the `pip` error and cannot check it because I've no OS X boxes available.

Regarding the `conda` error it is almost sure the well known conflict between `pyqt5 pip` package and `pyqt5 conda` package. A workaround is simply remove the `PyQt5` dependency from the file `Anaconda3\pkgs\vitables-3.0.0-0\Lib\site-packages\ViTables-3.0.0.egg-info\requires.txt` (I don't know if the path is the same on Mac OS X).

You can found it explained with some more detail in the [ViTables FAQ](http://vitables.org/Docs/faq.html#can-i-use-vitables-with-anaconda3).